# How can I generate a Terraform configuration file from existing infrastructure?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm new to Terraform. I have what seems like a simple problem, but I've been unable to come up with a solution.

I have an existing project not managed by Terraform, and I'd like to start using Terraform to manage it. What I'd like is an automated way to generate the configuration file so that I don't have to write it by hand.

If it matters, the project is in [GCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform) ([GKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform#Compute) specifically), so I think the only providers I should need are Google and Kubernetes. I tried using [this tool](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/export), but I have concerns about it due to the fact that it's in beta and the documentation states there are some resource types that aren't supported.

Is there a more standard or general-purpose way of achieving this? Can I perhaps generate a state file from my existing project and then import that? It feels like this shouldn't be difficult, so maybe I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: Your task sounds simple but is very complex. Terraform does not yet support everything in Google Cloud. Google has some support for exporting Google Cloud resources to Terraform: https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/export In summary, your objective is not achievable.

Comment: I'd use the tool you linked as a starting point.  I have used it myself and it is pretty good when it comes to GKE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code generation is still not available natively at this moment.

You can achieve a similar result by importing the resource and running a plan:

1. see the import instructions [at the bottom of the documentation page](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_bucket#import)
2. import the resource you want to terraform
3. run a `terraform plan`

The output of `terraform plan` will show all the code you need as a diff.

Comment: Re *"import the resource you want to terraform"*: [Terraform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraform_(software)) seems to be used as a verb. What exactly is meant by that?  Importing the resource and running a plan? Or something else? I suggest rephrasing it.

Comment: Nice. I basically did a version of this using Terraform workspaces and importing the resources I wanted Terraform to manage. Thank you!